# Counting bijections with a constraint

Tags: combinatorics

> Let $A$$=${$1,2,3,4,5$} . Find the number of bijective functions $f:A\to$ $A$ if $f(1)=2$.

I can't use the formula of bijective functions ( $n!$) , because the $f(1)=2$ is misleading me.

Comment: think on how you obtain that formula

Answer (score 1):

Think about what is going on: you have one fixed point, but you can do whatever you want with the other 4. So how many bijections do you have from a set of size 4 to itself?

Comment: I applied the formula $4!$" , is this correct?

Comment: @newbiebutperseverent Do you understand why $4!$ is the correct answer? Why does that count the number of bijections?

Comment: hmm , no , i'm a little bit confused because at the end of my book says that $4!$ is calculated by arrangements.

Comment: @newbiebutperseverent $4! = 4*3*2*1$. You want to find the bijections of a set with 4 elements. This means that only one object can map onto each object in the image. So for the first element, 1, you have 4 possible choices of where to map it. For the second, you one point in the image is 'taken', so you only have 3 choices. For the third, two points are 'taken', and for the fourth there is only one possibility left: 4*3*2*1 = 4! possibilities. Does that make it clearer?

Comment: yes,thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You need to count the bijections between $A\setminus\{1\}=\{2,3,4,5\}$ and $A\setminus\{2\}=\{1,3,4,5\}$, since that is what is left to choose. The set are not the same set , but they have the same size, which is all that matters for counting the bijections.